# Any idea why this query keeps timing out?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

so this seemingly simple query keeps timing out.  There are only ~ 61K records in my filtered DE, though there are about 120 attributes, though most don't have any data. When I run the query without any joins, it completes in under 10 seconds.  Adding the join to the Sent data view and we time out.

I had originally used xtshortdate for the Sent Date, but I wanted to try and get the time in there too, which xtshortdate doesn't have, so that's why we have the Sent data view join.  Also, we use a variable for our subject lines so that's why I joined to the Job data view.

[image: SQL example]

Comment: Must be the 120 attributes, doesn’t matter if they have data or not. Create a copy of that DE with less attributes and try to join that?

Comment: Also, please include your query as text, not a screenshot

Comment: is there a 1:1 on jobid or a N:N?

Comment: _Sent is the largest and least performant data view, so I'm not surprised.  How many records are in your Send Log?

Comment: Already mentioned, but yeah - that _Sent table is massive and you're joining to a Filtered DE (those always seem to be a bit slow in my experience). I'd add a clause to your query to do it by month (since you only have 6 months of data in _Sent), using Add/Update as your target method. That is, do one WHERE DateDiff(month,EventDate,GetDate()) = 6, then when that one is complete, replace 6 with 5, then 5 with 4, etc.